# How to clean metadata of an excel file using python?

Tags: python-3.x, excel, metadata

The task is to remove metadata of an excel file using python3.

- openpyxl, somehow, removed the metadata but it is not grown enough to convert Text Areas.

Any other alternative packet suggestion to have this task done?

```py
import base64
import io
import magic
import openpyxl

def remove_metadata_from_excel_base64(base64_file):
    # Decoding base64 file
    decoded_file = base64.b64decode(base64_file)
    # Checking MIME type
    mime_type = magic.from_buffer(decoded_file, mime=True)
    if mime_type != 'application/vnd.ms-excel':
        raise ValueError('Invalid file format. Excel file expected.')

    # Loading workbook from decoded file
    with io.BytesIO(decoded_file) as file_buffer:
        workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(file_buffer)

    # Clearing workbook properties (metadata)
    workbook.properties.clear()

    # Saving modified workbook to a new file buffer
    with io.BytesIO() as modified_file_buffer:
        workbook.save(modified_file_buffer)
        modified_file_buffer.seek(0)

        # Encoding modified file to base64
        modified_base64_file = base64.b64encode(modified_file_buffer.read())

    # Closing workbook
    workbook.close()
    print(modified_base64_file)
    return modified_base64_file
base64_file=""
remove_metadata_from_excel_base64(base64_file)
```